# How do I get a fixed column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

What I want is basically a table like this https://gyazo.com/5f7a50bd26b1ab63194c2b837d22f556 (taken from ntask website). The first and last column fixed. The middle data has an overflow. The ntask website has a unique table made with flexbox, I was wondering if this could be done with html table instead?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
// @ts-nocheck
const users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
export default function App() {
  const [userList, setUserList] = React.useState(users);
  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <div className="table">
        <table
          id="user-list-table"
          className="table table-striped"
          role="grid"
          data-toggle="data-table"
        >
          <thead>
            <tr className="light">
              <th>Col one</th>
              <th>Col two</th>
              <th>Col three</th>
              <th>Col four</th>
              <th>Col five</th>
              <th>Col six</th>
              <th>Col seven</th>
              <th>Col eight</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {userList.map((item, idx) => (
              <tr key={idx}>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
                  {' '}
                  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                  by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
                  The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                  normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
                  here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                  Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use
                  Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for
                  'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
                  infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years,
                  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour
                  and the like).
                </td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kyj4vy?file=App.tsx,index.html

What I want is the scroll-able overflow X to only appear on col 3 to col 6. Col 1, 2 and 7,8, should be visible at all screens.

I tried the position sticky solution, but then the overflow-x extends the entire table and looks weird to me.

Comment: I hope this helps, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dvy2pq?file=style.css

Comment: Ideally I don't want the overflow X to extend on the fixed columns. Is it possible to do columns 1 and 2 fixed. And 7 and 8 fixed instead through this way ? I think this solution looks awkward if  there are more columns.

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand that sentence at first. However, I think it's not possible unless you split it into three tables or use flex display instead.

Comment: I'll try splitting three tables thanks for the idea

Comment: Example for using flex display https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cetohz?file=App.tsx,style.css

Comment: This is exactly what I need but again I need it as an HTML table. (im refactoring a table code, it will be way more work to do for multiple tables that I currently have, as there are other table specific in the existing code).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done but it would require some css and `position: fixed` attributes

```
const users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
export default function App() {
  const [userList, setUserList] = React.useState(users);
  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <div className="table">
        <table
          id="user-list-table"
          className="table table-striped"
          role="grid"
          data-toggle="data-table"
        >
          <thead>
            <tr className="light">
              <th id="colOne">Col one</th>
              <th id="colTwo">Col two</th>
              <th id="colThree">Col three</th>
              <th >Col four</th>
              <th>Col five</th>
              <th>Col six</th>
              <th id="colSeven">Col seven</th>
              <th id="colEight">Col eight</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {userList.map((item, idx) => (
              <tr key={idx}>
                <td id="f-row" style={{ position: 'fixed' }}>
                  1
                </td>
                <td id="colTwo" style={{ position: 'fixed' }}>
                  2
                </td>
                <td id="colThree">3</td>
                <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
                  {' '}
                  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
                  by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
                  The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                  normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
                  here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                  Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use
                  Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for
                  'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
                  infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years,
                  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour
                  and the like).
                </td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the CSS would be

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
#colOne {
  padding-right: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0px;
}
#colTwo {
  padding-right: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background:inherit;

}

#colThree {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

#f-row {
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

This is for column 1 and 2 being fixed to the page
You can then replicate the styling for 7 and 8

Comment: This doesn't work. The columns are overlapping. Also the overflow X extends the entire screen I specifically do not want that.